# How can you bootstrap instead of an old JQuery div pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a PHP button that opens a modal.  It then works off an old java script code for an older JQuery.  I am trying to upgrade it to Bootstrap and not sure what I am doing wrong - the window pops up, but the Yes button won't work.  The No button just closes the modal.

PHP code creates a remove button (I tried adding a Modal to it that does pop up):

```
if (can2('delete audit')) {
                $admin_actions .= "

                <a data-toggle=\"modal\"  data-target=\"#myModal\" href=\"#\" id=\"$row[auditID]\" class=\"remove modify\" Title=\"Remove\" ><span class=\"hidding\">Remove</span></a>";
            }
```

Old Code:

```
<div id="question_alert" class="question_alert" >
    <div id="alert">
        Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this Audit? You will not be able to get it back.
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " />
    <input type="button" id="no_delete" value="No" />
</div>
```

New code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal header-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">DELETE?</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-body">

           <p>Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this Audit? You will not be able to get it back. </p>
        </div>
    <!-- Modal Footer-->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div id="question_alert" class="question_alert">
        <!-- problem here for yes -->
            <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " />
    <input type="button" id="no_delete" value="No"  data-dismiss="modal" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

old code JQuery used for the yes button mainly:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
var auditID = this.id;
$.blockUI({message: $('#question_alert')});
//Continue with unanswered questions
$('#yes_delete').click(function() {
  $.post("edit_audits.php?action=delete&auditID="+auditID,function(data) {

    if(data) alert(data);
      $.growlUI('Success','You have successfully DELETED the audit.','success',1000);
       setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.reload();
      }, 2000);
    return false;
  }); 
});
//Fix answered questions
$('#no_delete').click(function() {
  $.unblockUI();
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: is `can2` a php function ? Hope this is not javascript at least...

Comment: definately is, even uses the `.=` concatenator

Comment: Actually, this is all JQuery, when I looked at the code at first some parts made me think it could be javascript